# how to view record within date range?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I have a records in my table **Test** like this my **Date** column is of type varchar.

```
Fname      Lname      Date  
vivek      parikh     01-09-2011 10:00:00 PM  
kashyap    vyas       02-09-2011 10:50:00 AM  
viral      panchal    02-09-2011 10:00:00 PM  
Arpit      Gosai      03-09-2011 10:00:00 PM  
Darshit    Chokshi    04-09-2011 10:00:00 PM  
Sameer     Rangrez    24-08-2011 9:15:12 AM
```

i want to fetch records within date range (start date and end date) from page.

my code is

```
 DateTime time = DateTime.Today;             // Use current time
    string format = "MM-dd-yyyy";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Fname,Lname,Insert_Date from Test where Insert_Date >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text).ToString(format) + "' and Insert_Date <= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text).ToString(format) + "'  ", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Fname"].ToString());
        Response.Write(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Lname"].ToString());
        Response.Write(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Insert_Date"].ToString()+"<br>");
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which version of C#? A short LINQ-statement should give you a really nice solution.

Comment: Is this pulling from a database? If so, what database is it? Or is it held in memory?

Comment: yes its from sql server 2008 r2..

Comment: If its in sql server 2008 then a simple date comparison using < or > will not work because the column type is varchar. Please explain what do you want as a solution, do you need a sql query or you want a linq expression for getting that data ?

Comment: i want sql query from which i can fetch the accurate date with comparison of date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for building your query use [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)(datetime,fieldname,103) for converting varchar to datetime.

Your query should be something like.

select * from Test
where **Convert(datetime,field_date,103) >= '2011-01-01'** --start date

and **Convert(datetime,field_date,103) <= '2012-01-01'**; --end date

This is how your C# statement should look like (It should include **103** code to specify your date format which dd-mm-yyyy

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Fname,Lname,Insert_Date from Test where Convert(datetime,Insert_Date,103) >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text).ToString(format) + "' and Convert(datetime,Insert_Date,103) <= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text).ToString(format) + "'  ", con);
```

Comment: it gives me "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"

Comment: You are getting it because I forgot to specify the style number 103 for your date. See the following link for style formats [link]http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Answer (score 0):

SELECT colname FROM tablename WHERE somecol >= '2011-01-09' AND somecol <= '2011-09-24'

Answer (score 0):

select * from Test where Date >= '2011-09-02' and Date < '2011-0-04'

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) SQL operator. Also make sure you are formatting the dates correctly using the standard SQL Server format to avoid and potential confusion: yyyymmdd hhmmss, and remember to take the time portion of the date into account as well.

Answer (score 0):

The following sql statement has been tested against our companys sql server 2008 and works fine.

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE date_field >= '2011-10-25' and date_field <= '2011-11-26'
```